# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type X, but this dictionary requires a model item of type Y

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have searched through many answers for that problem (some say even that is a bug) but I can´t figure out where is thr problem for me. I have cleaned all my code but still having error message when I i got the view. Everything works fine in the debug line by line. But in the end YSOFD...

Here is my code:

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        ViewBag.Tema = (new tema()).Css;

        //Pega dados do formulário
        foreach (string _formData in formCollection)
        {
            ViewData[_formData] = formCollection[_formData];
        }


        GameViewModel selectJogo = new sjnj.Models.GameViewModel();


            string sqlJogo = "SELECT id,nome FROM Jogo where nome like '%" +            ViewData["formNomeGame"].ToString() + "%' ORDER BY NOME";
            DataTable dtBuscajogo = new DataAccess("mjnj").ExecuteDataTable(sqlJogo);
            selectJogo.selectListajogo = new System.Data.DataTable();
            selectJogo.selectListajogo.Columns.Add("id");
            selectJogo.selectListajogo.Columns.Add("nome");

            selectJogo.selectListajogo.Rows.Add("#", "Selecione...");

            if (dtBuscajogo.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtBuscajogo.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    selectJogo.selectListajogo.Rows.Add(dtBuscajogo.Rows[i]["id"], dtBuscajogo.Rows[i]["nome"]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.MensagemError = "Nenhum jogo encontrado";
            }

    return View("Insert",selectJogo);
```

Model -- Note that i have commented everything

```
namespace sjnj.Models
{
public class GameViewModel
{
    #region Inserir
    //[Display(Name = "Adcionar jogo a sua coleção")]
    //public string lblAdcionarJogo { get; set; }
    //[Display(Name = "Digite o nome do jogo")]
    //public string lblDigiteJogo { get; set; }
    //[Display(Name = "Selecione o jogo")]
    //public string lblSelecioneJogo { get; set; }

    //[Display(Name = "descrição do jogo selecionado")]
    //public string descrJogoSelecionado { get; set; }
    //[Display(Name = "Jogo Selecionado")]
    //public string nomeJogoSelecionado { get; set; }

   // [Display(Name = "Saiba mais")]
   //public string saibaMaisSele { get; set; }

   //[Display(Name = "Jogo digitado pelo usuario")]
   //public string formNomeGame  { get; set; }

    //[Display(Name = "Lista dos jogos")]
   // public DataTable selectListajogo { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
}
```

My view

```
@model sjnj.Models.GameViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Home.cshtml";
}
```

And thats my only view that is giving error. Only when I declare the view to fill in data.

**Edit:** The explicit error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'sjnj.Models.RegisterViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type 'sjnj.Models.HomeViewModel'.

Comment: When does the YSOD occur? When doing a POST for the Insert action?

Comment: Yep! When you open the page first, it´s ok!

Comment: Try turning-off the implicit evaluation of properties in the debugger options. If the stepping through the program is what makes a difference between success and failure, then the debugger is probably interfering by calling a piece of code that would not normally be called at that point in time (or be called at all).

Comment: YSOFD = Yello Screen Of The Death :D

Answer (score 0):

I got the error.

My MasterPage was also using a model. When I call the master page (layout) it uses the model then a call the view whit another model it messed up (I don´t know exactlty what happens.

So the solution is to make make **another view just for the dynamic part of the master page**, in that case, the user menu.

I don´t know ho to do it exactly how, but I know where the error is.

Comment: If part of your master view needs its own model, one thing that can often help is the Html.Action method. It lets you spin up an entirely new ControllerContext to render that part of your page.